# Why did this line delete everything in my MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, database

Ok, so I'm trying to roll out a small update to my site. One update includes querying upon a field that may or may not exist. This doesn't work as I want, so I decided to just make it so that the field always exists in my database. I used this line at the MongoDB shell:

```
> db.entries.update({Published: null},{$set: {Published: true}},false,true);
```

Now, I'm not fully understanding how this caused every entry object where Published is null to be deleted. I mean, it literally was deleted. I tried looking up some IDs, and .findOne will return null for them.

How does that line work? I thought it would take every entry where Published is null(doesn't exist), and set Published to true.

Answer (score 3):

Reading about operator behavior is better than guessing operator behavior. Search for null is different from performing a check for existence.

MongoDB has a dedicated $exists operator:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists

Comment: And this illustrates the need to test your updates on a staging database before running it in a production environment.

Comment: LOL - of course....if you are running such updates without knowing about the impact in production without having it tested properly in a testing environment then this deserves only the label "unprofessional".

Comment: @Bryan @Rest well, it was only for my small blog, and I had backups. Next time will definitely run this in a staging database though. But even then. I'm not understanding how checking `==null` and `exists` will change the behavior of deleting everything

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure why it now works with changes, or at least, why it deleted everything with that command.

My ending command looked like this:

```
db.entries.update({Published: {$exists: false},$atomic: true},{$set:{"Published":true}},false,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it would take every entry where Published is null(doesn't exist), and set Published to true.

OK, so these are two different things.

Published is null:

```
{ Published : null, post : 'blah' }
```

Published does not exist:

```
{ post : 'blahblah' }
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why it deleted every object where Published was not set though

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post this question over at the MongoDB user group (developers check it very often) at http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user

Answer (score 0):

Updates do not delete documents.  In fact, the update you ran does what you intended, for example, if you wanted `y` to always have a value:

```
> db.foo.insert({x:1})
> db.foo.insert({x:2})
> db.foo.insert({y:null})
> db.foo.insert({y:1})
> db.foo.update({y:null},{$set : {y:true}}, false, true)
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4db02aabbe5a5418fb65d24c"), "y" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4db02aafbe5a5418fb65d24d"), "y" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4db02aa1be5a5418fb65d24a"), "x" : 1, "y" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4db02aa4be5a5418fb65d24b"), "x" : 2, "y" : true }
```

There must have been another operation that did the delete.  There might be a record of it in the logs (or there might not... it depends how long it took).  It's impossible to tell from the info here what caused the deletions, but the update isn't the culprit here.

Comment: Ah, so the delete should actually have no happened? That's odd because it's not like there is much that runs on my MongoDB instance, so I'm not that concerned with parallel operations.